# Add '2 second pause' in click to call service

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am developing a web page to provide click to call service.
I want to add a '2 sec pause' after dialing the number +919999999999, like this

```
<a href="tel:+919999999999,456"></a>
```

shows +919999999999 in  dialer in android phone, it ignores anything after comma
I have tried several other ways like :

```
<a href="tel:+919999999999p456"></a>
```

shows +9199999999997456, p is converted to 7

```
<a href="tel:+919999999999;ext=456"></a>
<a href="tel:+919999999999;postd=456"></a>
```

shows +919999999999  only.None of them seems to be working.Above cases works fine with IOS and Blackberry.Please suggest me the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "w" for hard pause. Read from [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/05/10/how-to-add-hard-wait-and-soft-2-3-sec-pauses-to-your-android-contacts/).

Comment: w is converting to 9 in the dialer and after the number becomes invalid

Comment: According to my knowledge so far. "," comma is used for pause in android. I think HTML is converting comma into something else like "p" to 7 and "w" to 9.

Comment: Yes i also tried this, but it doesn't work.Dialer is ignoring any special character

Comment: ',' is used as 2 sec pause universally , tel scheme are working fine in iphone but only creates issue in android. ',',p are working fine other than android

Answer (score 0):

You can add a series of , characters, which will create a brief pause like this.

```
<a href="tel:+919999999999,,,456"></a>
```

If three `,` not work then try to increase character.

Comment: I have tried both the approaches, but it doesn't work. I think Android dialer is ignoring all special characters and aphabets are converted to corresponding numbers.In these cases 'pp' converts to 77 and everything after comma is not working

Comment: I didn;t understand what u want? The code which opens dialer showing number is this single line only

Comment: are u using webview to load html page?

Comment: can u pls post your activity class so i can check it

Comment: Currently i am only trying to use it as normal html.